# How to call vairable inside FTP file in unix/linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am writing a ksh file which will create FTP a file to the ftp location ..

I have this file my_pwd file where i have declare all the variables s below :-

```
# File for set environment for systemuser
##
#
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client
#export PWD= CONNECT-STRING-PROVIDED-BY-DBA
export RUNTIME=/abc/batch/pte/scripts
PATH=$PATH:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client/bin/
export PATH
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1
MY_PW="test/123@pttest.pte.com" export my_PW
RUNTIME="/abc/batch/pte/scripts"; export RUNTIME
OUTDIR="/abc/batch/pte/outdir"; export OUTDIR
export ILC_HOME=/abc/batch/pte/scripts/logcheck
export ILC_CONNECT=ilc_abc/ilc_abc@pte.pte.com.com
export TEST_TP_SERVER=PTTEST-0012.pte.com
export TEST_TP_USER_ID=xxx
export TEST_TP_USER_PWD=yyy123
```

I am creating the test.ksh file as below :-

```
cd ${RUNTIME}
NOW=$(date +"%y%m%d%H%M%S")
ftp -i -n -v ${TEST_TP_SERVER} <<END
user $TEST_TP_USER_ID $TEST_TP_USER_PWD
lcd ${OUTDIR}
put "TEST.txt" "$NOW.ABC"
quit
END
```

After this I can see "Transfer complete" message .
But it is not creating in ="/abc/batch/pte/outdir" location . It is creating in my home location .

Can anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Chk  the access permissions on the destination folder

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be connecting the two files. Put this as the first line of `test.ksh`:

```
. /path/to/my_pwd
```

In Bourne-type shell languages the dot command "sources" the named file, i.e. executes it in the current shell. After that, your script will have access to the variables.

Comment: The set up is like this , we need to create 2 files , one will contain all the valriables and 2nd one will have ksh file . So I cant change that set up . Even I tried with your solution , but still the same .

Comment: Actually problem is it is taking from the crooect directory , But it should also create the new file with $NOW.abc, in the same directory , which is not happening . It is creating in my local directory .